# Displaying OBJ files with color

Tags: graphics, visualization, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I am reading .obj files for my program, and doing curvature computations on them. The present .obj files are triangle meshes, with vertices and faces. They don't have any associated .mtl file. Based on the curvature, I have to assign a color to each vertex, and they are different for all the vertices. I want to display the .obj file now, but I want the vertices to be colored based on the color I assign to them. What is the best way of displaying such a file?

Initially I thought of writing my own .mtl file and modify my input .obj file as well. But as the number of vertices are of the order of ~50000, each having its own color, specifying a .mtl file with ~50000 materials seems to be very daunting indeed.

I read somewhere that .ply files can handle colors more easily, but am not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks in advance for any help. I am a newbie when it comes to visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that saving mesh with vertex colors in [PLY file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) is much easier, and you will get one file containing everything: triangles, vertices and colors.

For that one has to specify in PLY file header after

```
element vertex _numVertices_
property float x
property float y
property float z
```

3 additional properties for RGB vertex colors:

```
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
```

where `uchar` means one unsigned char per color component.

Then in the body of PLY, each vertex will be represented by 3 `float` vertex coordinates and 3 `uchar`s for vertex RGB color.

One of the implementation is in [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme), see

```cpp
/// saves in .ply file
MRMESH_API tl::expected<void, std::string> toPly( const Mesh& mesh, const std::filesystem::path& file, const Vector<Color, VertId>* colors = nullptr,
                                                  ProgressCallback callback = {} );
MRMESH_API tl::expected<void, std::string> toPly( const Mesh & mesh, std::ostream & out, const Vector<Color, VertId>* colors = nullptr,
                                                  ProgressCallback callback = {} );
```